# What is the correct way to implement decoupled code / callbacks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, observer-pattern

I have several different JavaScript objects with methods that i want to keep separate. However, I need some type of observer, callback, or plugin design so that I can trigger these methods at the correct time.

For example, `A.Foo()` should almost always run *after* `B.Bar()` - but I do not want to place a call to  `A.Foo()` *inside* `B.Bar()` because there are those odd times it *should not* run after `B.Bar()`. That would be coupling my code and I know that's bad.

I want to approach this problem as if `B.Bar()` is just doing it's job and does not ever plan on knowing about `A.Foo()` or any other function that might want to tag along with it. In other words, plugin support for future developers.

How do you design modular, non-coupled code with observer or event based callbacks in Javascript?

Comment: This question might be over my head, but could you set some kind of global boolean variable in `A.Foo()` to true and have `B.Bar()` immediately return if the global variable is false?

Comment: @Travesty3, that would work - but it would make the code coupled to not only both functions, but a random global variable also.

Comment: The answer to this depends on your code structure. The most general would be to pass in a function to call in `B.Bar()`. Otherwise it depends on what you're actually doing, you could also use some sort of deferred-style mechanism so you don't need to pass it in.

Comment: Do you mind about putting some "well-known" object, like observer (you mentioned it in your original post) that both A.Foo and B.Bar will know about? Also, do you mind about using jQuery or you would like to have a completely 3rd-party libraries independent solution?

Comment: something similar to function chaining?

Comment: @DenisMazourick, I use jQuery on almost all projects so I don't mind having using it for this also. I just ran across [microevent](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/microevent.js) which is like that "well-known" object you talk about. I think backbone.js does this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether your scenario is really event like in nature, or more of an asynchronous operation:

### Event Based

Using something like [microevent](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/microevent.js) you could do the following.  This pattern is really common and simple, so I suggest that at some point you have a go at implimenting this yourself, as it's great from an understanding point of view.

```
MicroEvent.mixin(A);

A.Foo = function () {
  //Do stuff A needs to do, then:
  A.trigger('foo-complete');
};

//Somewhere nice and separate and decoupled
A.bind('foo-complete', B.Bar);
```

If you need to do more complex things like filter the events, map the events etc.  Reactive Extensions (which are based of the C# libraries) are really powerful, but that's a big library to load in if you don't need the functionality.

### Async operation

#### Using Callbacks

This can be done using callbacks, which is great for fairly simple operations:

```
A.Foo = function (cb) {
  //Do stuff A needs to do, then:
  if (cb) cb();
};

A.Foo(B.Bar);
```

#### Using promises

These initially look more complicated, but they are easilly composable, and have nice ways of handling errors built in.

Using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which is one of the more popular promise libraries (again, there are loads of these):

```
A.Foo = function () {
  var def = Q.defer();
  setTimeout(function () {
    //Simulate async operation
    def.resolve();
  }, 1000);
  return def.promise;
};

A.Foo().then(B.Bar).end();
```

#### Using control flow libraries

Control flow libraries (arguably promises are a special case of this) aim to help you compose operations that are based on the callback system.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo allows you to listen to function calls.

```
dojo.connect("foo", A, function(){
  B.bar();
});
```